# Possible to center dynamic uneven added columns in foundation in one row?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, center, grid-layout

Im trying to resolve a small but irritating problem I got. That I haven´t found a solution on even when I googled...

I want to center a "unknown" uneven number columns in foundation. I cant figure out how to do it...
Since it´s unknown I dont know when to use offset or the right columnsize.

[I "Codepenned" a example of the problem.](http://codepen.io/Roesler/pen/RrrEgx?editors=110)

This problem is "solveable" in Bootstrap at least...

Here is a example of my problem if CodePen dosen´t work.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 small-centered large-centered columns blue-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-3 columns test">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250&text=[Center us without offset or adding cols]">
      </div>
      <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-3 columns test">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250&text=[Center us without offset or adding cols]">
      </div>
      <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-3 columns test">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250&text=[Center us without offset or adding cols]">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 small-centered large-centered columns blue-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-3 columns test">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250&text=[Center us without offset or adding cols]">
      </div>
      <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-3 columns test">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250&text=[Center us without offset or adding cols]">
      </div>
      <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-3 columns test">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250&text=[Center us without offset or adding cols]">
      </div>
       <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-3 columns test">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250&text=[Center us without offset or adding cols]">
      </div>
       <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-3 columns test">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250&text=[Center us without offset or adding cols]">
      </div>
       <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-3 columns test">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250&text=[Center us without offset or adding cols]">
      </div>
       <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-3 columns test">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250&text=[Center us without offset or adding cols]">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 small-centered large-centered columns blue-container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-3 columns test">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250&text=[Center us without offset or adding cols]">
      </div>
       <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-3 columns test">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250&text=[Center us without offset or adding cols]">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.blue-container{
  background-color:blue;
}

.test{
 background-color:green; 
}

.col-wrapper{
  margin-left:auto!important;
  margin-right:auto!important;
  /*Is this something to use maybe?*/
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I found a answer by this solution: [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/).

So what I did was this: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Roesler/pen/WrrPee?editors=110)
I took away row and col-sizes, measured the sise of the large column, used only small for some auto-styles.
I added a wrapper like this:

SCSS

```
.center-blocks {
text-align: center;

    &:before {
        display: inline-block !important;
        height: 100%;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
}

.centered-block {
    display: inline-block !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And the HTML Looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 small-centered large-centered columns blue-container">
    <div class="center-blocks">
      <div class="small-3 centered-block">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250&text=[Center us without offset or adding cols]">
      </div>
      <div class="small-3 centered-block">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250&text=[Center us without offset or adding cols]">
      </div>
      <div class="small-3 centered-block">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250&text=[Center us without offset or adding cols]">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see the result here:[CodePen](http://codepen.io/Roesler/pen/WrrPee?editors=110).